# Connect to windows share over vpn - on an Android device

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, android, nas

I'm having some difficulties connecting my Android devices to a Windows share over VPN.

**Background**
I've bought a Synology DS214se NAS, which I have installed in my home network. I have configured the NAS to run a VPN (PPTP) server. The DNS name of the NAS is diskstation, and its IP address is fixed; 192.168.1.13. My Android devices are a smartphone running Android 4.2.2 and a tablet running Android 4.4.2, and I'm using the built-in Android VPN client.

When I'm on my home network, I can acces the Windows shares on my NAS on both my Windows PC and on my Android devices.

When I'm on an external network with my Windows PC, I can connect to the VPN server and then access the shared folders.

**The Problem**
With my Android devices, I can connect to the VPN server. However, I cannot find the Windows shares. I have tried to connect to smb://192.168.13 or smb://diskstation and 192.168.1.3 or diskstation using the ES File Explorer app.

I haven't been able to come up with a solution myself yet, and I've also searched alot for a solution without luck.

So if you have any ideas that might point me in the right direction, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my sonicwall and ES fm. I installed Ghost Commander along with its SMB plugin and instantly was able to see my server files over the VPN via both IP and computer name. I never did get ES to work - it just spins while looking for files over the VPN...

Comment: Ghost Commander works for me as well, but the interface is archaic and I found it to be a little clunky overall.  I now have something that works but I am still searching for an alternative.